# Why is Gatling failing on a valid jsonpath?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have the following .check on my returned body: (I changed the values for security reasons but the structure is the same)

```
 .exec(http("Get ids")
          .post("GetIds")
          .body(ElFileBody("json/getIds.json")).asJson
          .check(jsonPath("$...Types..[?(@.Type == 'web')].id").findAll.saveAs("IDLlist"))
```

But the transaction fails with "Gettting findAll.exists extraction crashed: end of input expected when trying to extract values from a returned body"

Gatling prints the body of the failed transaction, when I take the exact body that the transaction had just failed on to http://jsonpath.com/ and
evaluate the jsonpath that had just failed, I get good results with no issues. This means that the returned body is correct and that the jsonpath is also correct. 
What is the issue then?

Comment: Can you post some of the json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Stephane from the Gatling forum, I found that $..Files[?(@.Format == 'DASH_Web')].URL is correct works instead of the variation that I had.

Since http://jsonpath.com/ was able to extract the correct path using my original syntax, I think its important to note that Gatling jsonpath is much more conservative in its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your JSON path syntax is wrong --> "$...Types..[?(@.Type == 'web')].id"

Try using JSONPath Online Evaluator -- http://jsonpath.com/ to find correct json syntax