# JSON body response find index for value

Tags: arrays, json, scala, indexing, gatling

Given this JSON response:

```
[{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"HELFO","brukerGruppe":"Brukerstøtte"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"Klubbgaten Legesenter","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"Sjøsiden Legesenter","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"Athene legekontor Helsedirektoratet","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"Xeon Legekontor","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"Østmarka legekontor","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"Hultemyra shamansamling","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"AMIS Testsenter","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"GLØSHAUGEN LEGESENTER DA","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"Helse Møre og Romsdal HF","brukerGruppe":"Lege"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"St. Olavs hospital HF","brukerGruppe":"Saksbehandler"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"HELSEDIREKTORATET","brukerGruppe":"Saksbehandler"},{"brukergruppeSperret":false,"virksomhetsnavn":"Østmarka legekontor","brukerGruppe":"Saksbehandler"}]
```

I want to obtain the first index in the JSON response that has the value "Lege" as "brukerGruppe".
In the above example this corresponds to index 6.

How can I in session in Gatling do a check that implements this?
I guess the function "find" could be used somewhat like this:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.brukerGruppe").find("Lege").indexvalue ??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JsonPath support condition and you can find like this:

```
jsonPath("$.[6][?(@.brukerGruppe=='Lege')]"
```

It's returned :

```
[
  {
    "brukergruppeSperret": false,
    "virksomhetsnavn": "Hultemyra shamansamling",
    "brukerGruppe": "Lege"
  }
]
```

---

You can also get all items where **brukerGruppe** equals **Lege**

```
$.[?(@.brukerGruppe=='Lege')]
```

Comment: I only need the index of the first occurrence where “brukergruppe” has the value “Lege” and I want to save that position in the response array (it can vary)

Comment: `$.[1][?(@.brukerGruppe=='Lege')]`

Comment: I think you  misunderstood. What if brukergruppe=lege is at the position 3 in the responsebody? I do not want to ask at a certain position, but if it exist at all (it is not there for every response i.e). The rationale being if it is there, save the position in the jsonbody as an int, if not there skip it regardless of where it is positioned)

Comment: Tried  .check(jsonPath("$.[?(@.brukerGruppe=='Lege')]").saveAs("valgtBrukergruppe")) but I get 
-- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> jsonPath($.[?(@.brukerGruppe=='Lege')]).find.exists extraction      1 (100,0%)
 crashed: end of input expected

Comment: this was solved with .check(jsonPath("$..[?(@.brukerGruppe=='Lege')]").saveAs("valgtBrukergruppe")) because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910079/why-is-gatling-failing-on-a-valid-jsonpath

Comment: the response from the working example above saves this: {"brukergruppeSperret":false,"brukerGruppe":"Lege","virksomhetsnavn":"Klubbgaten Legesenter"}. However what I want is the actual position of the occurence. it could be at node 1, 2 or not at all. How do I obtain WHERE" in the json response body the "lege" exists in? how to save the array index position?

Comment: `What if brukergruppe=lege is at the position 3 in the responsebody` - 
It doesn't matter becauce  we make a selection and get only items with brukergruppe=lege.


It's mean we selection all items where brukerGruppe=='Lege' and THEN get first item
`$.[1][?(@.brukerGruppe=='Lege')]`

Comment: The point being I want to get the index value and use it in subsequent call. It can vary. How do I count "where" (understand: which position) the first ever brukerGruppe=='Lege' is located?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187610/index-of-value-in-json-responsebody-gatling-scala